# Unable to display any output

Tags: python, python-2.7

Guys I am new to Python but I am trying to get my windows 8 information using Python. But I am unable to do so, I can't find output of following code Its displays nothing.I am using Netbeans.

```
    # To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
# To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import os
    import re

def sys_info():
    values  = {}
    cache   = os.popen2("SYSTEMINFO")
    source  = cache[1].read()
    sysOpts = ["Host Name", "OS Name", "OS Version", "Product ID", "System Manufacturer", "System Model", "System type", "BIOS Version", "Domain", "Windows Directory", "Total Physical Memory", "Available Physical Memory", "Logon Server"]

    for opt in sysOpts:
        values[opt] = [item.strip() for item in re.findall("%s:\w*(.*?)\n" % (opt), source, re.IGNORECASE)][0]
    return values
    if values == null :
        print "yep"
        print (values)
```

Comment: sys_info is defined but never called so there is nothing to print

Answer (score 0):

First of all your placement if `import` , `function` and `main` are out of sequence.

Here is correct sequence

```
import os
import re    

def SysInfo():
    values  = {}
    cache   = os.popen2("SYSTEMINFO")
    source  = cache[1].read()
    sysOpts = ["Host Name", "OS Name", "OS Version", "Product ID", "System Manufacturer", "System Model", "System type", "BIOS Version", "Domain", "Windows Directory", "Total Physical Memory", "Available Physical Memory", "Logon Server"]

    for opt in sysOpts:
        values[opt] = [item.strip() for item in re.findall("%s:\w*(.*?)\n" % (opt), source, re.IGNORECASE)][0]
    return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SysInfo()
```

even after this , the code is not generating any output. I've `windows 2010`and `python 2.7` . I am wondering if it has to do with `OS version`. I am not windows savvy, so Cant answer that.

However, if your goal is to get windows system details, you may want to install `wmi` module by
`pip install wmi`

Then use following code to get either detailed system info or individual attributes.

```
import wmi

x = wmi.WMI()    
systeminfo = x.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]

print systeminfo
Manufarturer = systeminfo.Manufacturer
Model = systeminfo.Model

print "Manufarturer =", Manufarturer
print "Model =", Model
```

Output :

*Does not include details of `print systeminfo`*

```
Manufarturer = Dell Inc.
Model = Latitude E5430 non-vPro
```

You can dig individual attributes related to [Win32_ComputerSystem class here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function that you have written.

```
import os
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    def sys_info():
        values  = {}
        cache   = os.popen2("SYSTEMINFO")
        source  = cache[1].read()
        sysOpts = ["Host Name", "OS Name", "OS Version", "Product ID", "System Manufacturer", "System Model", "System type", "BIOS Version", "Domain", "Windows Directory", "Total Physical Memory", "Available Physical Memory", "Logon Server"]

        for opt in sysOpts:
            values[opt] = [item.strip() for item in re.findall("%s:\w*(.*?)\n" % (opt), source, re.IGNORECASE)][0]
        return values
        if values == null :
            print "yep"
            print (values)

    # Now call the function here
    sys_info()
```